# Default Values in Java similar to python

Tags: java, python, mysql

I am working on making one of my projects more streamlined. I have a way that checks if a parameter of a function is empty by doing a bunch of if statements. I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution similar to default values in python? I have posted my current code below. Thanks!

I looked into ways about setting default values similar to python but java sadly doesn't support that.

```
/**
     * Updates a user defined address on the mySQL server
     * @param conn The mySQL connection
     * @param id The id of the address
     * @param number The new house number 
     * @param name The new street name
     * @param city The new city
     * @param state The new state
     * @param zip The new zip code
     */
    public static void update(Connection conn, int id, String number, String name, String city, String state, String zip) {
        Address address = Address.getBy(conn, "id", Integer.toString(id));
        if(number.equals("")) {
            number=address.getNumber();
        }
        if(name.equals("")) {
            name=address.getName();
        }
        if(city.equals("")) {
            city=address.getCity();
        }
        if(state.equals("")) {
            state=address.getState();
        }
        if(zip.equals("")) {
            zip=address.getZip();
        }
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE address SET number=?, name=?, city=?, state=?, zip=? WHERE id =?");
            ps.setString(1, number);
            ps.setString(2, name);
            ps.setString(3, city);
            ps.setString(4, state);
            ps.setString(5,zip);
            ps.setInt(6, id);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have default parameter values.

If you only need one or two, you can use method overloading, but this does not scale to arbitrary combinations of large number of parameters.

```
// optional parameters missing
void update(Connection c, int n){
   Address a = ...
   update(c, n, a.getNumber(), a.getName(), a.getCity(), a.getState())
}

// another version with all parameters given
void update(Connection c, int n, 
            String number, String name, String city, String state){ 
  ... 
}
```

So what you have now is probably best (I would make it null-safe as well, though).